# Printer configure with paper 3inch width

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 printAction() {

    console.log(document.getElementById("divcontentsonce"));
    console.log(document.getElementById("ifmcontentstoprint"));
    var content = document.getElementById("divcontentsonce");

    var pri = document.getElementById("ifmcontentstoprint").contentWindow;
    pri.document.write(content.innerHTML);
    pri.print();
  }
```

How to give css for print()?

After print the paper size should be 3 inch how can I do it in my code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS print...

HTML FILE

```
 <p>This font changes when you print it</p>
```

CSS FILE

```
p {
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

@media print {
  p {
    font-family:serif;
  }
}
```

Comment: I created a JSFiddle to show you how to get it working: https://jsfiddle.net/coaps1xf/